# Change Title of Bash on Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, ubuntu, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is it possible to change the title that Bash on Ubuntu on Windows displays in its title bar? By default it's set to `<username>@<computername>:<CWD>`. I'd like to, say, add `Bash on Ubuntu on Windows:` as a prefix to it.

I've tried some solutions that added different lines to `.bashrc` (such as using `xtitle`), but the problem is that BoUoW changes its title every time it changes the CWD, so it just immediately overrides whatever you set in `.bashrc`.

Is there a way to permanently either add a prefix or fully change the tile?

Comment: [This solutions](https://superuser.com/a/886247/945588) should work on WSL

Comment: Thank you, I found a somewhat similar line to the one described in that answer in my `.bashrc` and edited it to include the prefix `Ubuntu: `. It works as I wanted now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the title of the mintty window?](https://superuser.com/questions/362227/how-to-change-the-title-of-the-mintty-window)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using WSL you can edit `~/.bashrc` file in your distro. This also works for *Windows Terminal* at least in version 0.7.

You need to locate `\[\e]0;` as explained here: https://askubuntu.com/a/405769/808082.

The example from `.bashrc` for *Ubuntu 18.4*:

```bsh
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

This means the title is set to `${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\`.

In your case you need to change it to:

```bsh
PS1="\[\e]0;Bash on Ubuntu on Windows: ${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
```

Comment: This result in current directory only (no path): PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\W\a\]$PS1"